# Data driven icon size in SymbolLayer

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I was following the blog post from https://blog.mapbox.com/a-guide-to-the-android-symbollayer-api-5daac7b66f2c to add different symbols to a map.

Having different icons based on the feature value is already working, but changing the icon size, based on the "selected" property proves not as easy.

As it seems they changed/removed some methods/classes with the newer SDK i am not able to set the icon size based on a property value of the feature.

```
mapboxMap.addLayer(myLayer)
  .withProperties(
    PropertyFactory.iconSize(
      Function.property(
        "selected",
        Stops.categorical(
          Stop.stop(true, PropertyFactory.iconSize(1.5f)),
          Stop.stop(false, PropertyFactory.iconSize(1.0f))
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Thats how they did it in the example, but `Stops.categorical()` does not exist anymore.

Im using `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else looking for an answer thats how i did solve it

```
iconSize(
    match(get("selected"), // property selected is a number
        literal(1),        // default value
        stop(0, 0.75),     // if not selected set icon size to 0.75 of original value
        stop(1, 1)         // if selected set it to original size
    )
)
```